# Creating a mySQL database into a different path in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to organize mysql db files into a folder for easier manipulation when coding. How do u create the db into the directory or subdirectory where the python script for creating the database is found? The file is needed for manipulation in the future. Including the path after the SQL statement does not seem to work.
Where should the preferred path be written?

```
loanDB = mysql.connector.connect(
host = "localhost",
user = "root",
password = "password1234"
)
cursor = loanDB.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE contactdb")
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't let you choose location of the database (like Postgresql and MS-SQL-Server).  Nor is the database stored as a single file.

Comment: Not really sure why the location of the mysql database files is relevant from a python coding point of view, since your are not manipulating those files directly, only through mysql.

Comment: You cannot create database out of data directory. But you may create tables with the body files out of the database directory: [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-tablespace.html), then [CREATE TABLE ... TABLESPACE = ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).